# BroadcastReceiver vs IntentService on geofencing

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, geofencing

I'm building geofencing with IntentService right now, but I read other samples and forum comment, they use and recommending broadcast receiver than IntentService.

What's your recommendation? 
My app is running on Android Oreo which restricted background services.

Comment: I am also curious to hear if there is a real difference and, if so, why.